# Can output from JavaScript coverage tool Istanbul be published through TeamCity?

Tags: javascript, continuous-integration, teamcity, code-coverage

Is it possible to somehow publish reports from the JavaScript coverage analysis tool [Istanbul](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/) through [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)? That is to say, I want to integrate these results with TeamCity's coverage reporting facilities.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do it in a similar way as they did it with PHP http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/02/25/continuous-integration-for-php-using-teamcity/

Comment: Thanks, going to give it a shot.

Comment: Would you mind writing the solution out in your answer (just the necessary steps)? I don't think it's considered good etiquette to just provide links in answers on SO.

Comment: Linked content may go away, I've seen this happen in SO answers in the past. I can also recall that people have commented on SO that one shouldn't link to external answers.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

1. configure the build script to produce the HTML report (preferably in
   a zip archive).
2. configure build artifacts to publish the report as
   the build artifact to the server: at this point you can check that
   the archive is available in the build artifacts.
3. Report Tab to make the report available as an extra tab on the build
   or project level.

To configure a report tab, go to the Project Settings| Report Tabs page, click Create new report tab. Provide the details like report tab type (Build or Project level), tab title, artifacts and start page.

You will now see tab with the tab name you provided in the above step as you trigger your next build configuration.

Comment: I think the issue with this is that it won't integrate directly with the code coverage metrics that TeamCity shows on the cover page. That being said, if you don't mind that this is a good solution, similar to what you can do with OpenCover since that's not directly supported :)

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays this is possible via the `--reporter=teamcity` flag.

[See the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047752/teamcity-nyc-istanbul-generate-test-coverage-report)