# Teamcity + NYC + Istanbul - generate test coverage report

Tags: teamcity, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

I am trying to generate tests report into teamcity, everytime built is made. I've researched the several methods and ended up finding Istanbul's teamcity reporter: [teamcity](https://github.com/istanbuljs-archived-repos/istanbul-reports/tree/590e6b0089f67b723a1fdf57bc7ccc080ff189d7/lib/teamcity)

Now I am trying to integrate it into teamcity, but I've not found any instructions about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `script` target in your `package.json` that uses the reporter:

```
"script": {
  ...
  "coverage:teamcity": "nyc --reporter=teamcity mocha ...etc..."
  ...
}
```

Then, in your build step, simply invoke it via command line `npm run coverage:teamcity`

Teamcity will automatically parse the output and generate the coverage summary for you.